# Error when Compiling Cython into 32bit app

Tags: python, c#, c, cython

I have python code that I am using Cython to convert to C (in order to call from C# 32bit application).

1. When I use MSVC x86 Native Tool Command prompt to run:

> python setup.py build_ext --inplace --compiler=msvc
> I get the error:

python38.lib(python38.dll) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe' failed with exit status 1112

2. When I use MSVC X64 Native Tool command prompt, I try to first run: setenv /x86 but setenv is not recognized. However, I can build as x64 successfully. When I compile the resulting c code as dll to call from C#, it is not a surprise that I get the following memory access violation:

   System.AccessViolationException
   HResult=0x80004003
   Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory.
   This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

I was wondering how to solve this issue, and be able to build for x86.

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: You need to install and link to a 32 bit version of Python.

Comment: Thanks David. I uninstalled 64 bit Python, installed 32 bit Python, and repeated the build of the C#. I still get the same error. My debugging shows it passes:  Py_Initialize(), and import_Cfunctname(), but the next step crashes: Cfunctname(), and I get the same error: System.AccessViolationException HResult=0x80004003 Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. I was wondering if you have any suggestions ?

Comment: There definitely isn't enough information here to make much of a comment. Your best option is probably to compile the Cython module with debug symbols and hopefully that'll give you a bit more details about where it's failing when you run it in the debugger

Comment: Thanks again David, and I hope it is OK to let you know the updates.

I fixed the different architecture issue and it compiles and builds successfully. I was able to generate a dll to call it from C# (using dllimport). When running the C#, I find that it calls the dll and executes the functions: Py_Initialize() and import_funcname() (where funcname is the python function defined by cdef) then it produces run time error:

System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

and of course no Py_Finalize().